# Why Guava does not provide a way to transform map keys

Tags: java, guava

This question is kind of already posted here:
[How to convert Map<String, String> to Map<Long, String> using guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733142/how-to-convert-mapstring-string-to-maplong-string-using-guava)

I think the answer of CollinD is appropriate:

> All of Guava's methods for transforming and filtering produce lazy
>   results... the function/predicate is only applied when needed as the
>   object is used. They don't create copies. Because of that, though, a
>   transformation can easily break the requirements of a `Set`.
>
> Let's say, for example, you have a `Map<String, String>` that contains
>   both "1" and "01" as keys. They are both distinct `String`s, and so the
>   `Map` can legally contain both as keys. If you transform them using
>   `Long.valueOf(String)`, though, they both map to the value `1`. They are
>   no longer distinct keys. This isn't going to break anything if you
>   create a copy of the map and add the entries, because any duplicate
>   keys will overwrite the previous entry for that key. A lazily
>   transformed `Map`, though, would have no way of enforcing unique keys
>   and would therefore break the contract of a `Map`.

This is true, but actually I don't understand why it is not done because:

- When the key transformation happen, if 2 keys are "merged", a runtime exception could be raised, or we could pass a flag to indicate to Guava to take any value of the multiple possible values for the newly computed key (failfast/failsafe possibilities)
- We could have a Maps.transformKeys which produces a Multimap

Is there a drawback I don't see in doing such things?

Comment: Seems more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @CollinD suggests, there's no way to do this in a lazy way.  To implement `get`, you have to convert all the keys with your transformation function (to ensure any duplicates are discovered).

So applying `Function<K,NewK>` to `Map<K,V>` is out.

You could safely apply `Function<NewK,K>` to the map:

```
V value = innerMap.get( fn.apply(newK) );
```

I don't see a Guava shorthand for that--it may just not be useful enough.  You could get similar results with:

```
Function<NewK,V> newFn = Functions.compose(Functions.forMap(map), fn);
```