# A dict-like class that uses transformed keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like a dict-like class that transparently uses transformed keys on lookup, so that I can write

```
k in d          # instead of f(k) in d
d[k]            # instead of d[f(k)]
d.get(k, v)     # instead of d.get(f(k), v)
```

etc. (Imagine for example that `f` does some kind of canonicalization, e.g. `f(k)` returns `k.lower()`.)

It seems that I can inherit from `dict` and override individual operations, but not that there is a centralized spot for such transformation that all keys go through. That means I have to override all of `__contains__`, `__getitem__`, `get`, and possibly `__missing__`, etc. This gets too tedious and error-prone, and not very attractive unless this overhead outweighs that of manually substituting `f(k)` for every call on a plain `dict`.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense. I'm not sure how you'd go about it (without overriding a bunch of functions, as you say). Also, I'm not sure it's a great idea generally. A dict, that doesn't quite behave as one expects it too is a pretty dangerous thing.

Comment: You are correct that you must define each operation individually.  There is a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/) to add such a class to the `collections` module, and the PEP links to a Python bug with [a patch](http://bugs.python.org/file31761/transformdict3.patch) implementing it.  Also, by "overhead" I'm not sure whether you mean the overhead of writing a single class with a parameterized `f`, or a different class for each `f`.  If you write a class that allows you to specify `f`, then the implementation tedium is only suffered once, no matter how many different `f` you need.

Comment: What about overriding the `__init__` method so that it just stores `f(k)` instead of `k`, and if needed, store `k` separately? If you still need to "see" it as `k`, then just override the `__str__` method to show `k`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Thanks, that PEP 455 looks like the exact thing I want. By "overhead" I mean that of writing a single class, which could still feel too much for a project not concerned in library maintenance primarily. (In my case I have only a few call sites of `f`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your question is being downvoted, it's a reasonable thing to want.  In Java, Guava provides several map transformation utilities which provide views into the backing map like you're describing.  However they don't provide a `Maps.transformKeys()` method because it's actually not a very useful function.  See [How to convert Map<String, String> to Map<Long, String> using guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733142/how-to-convert-mapstring-string-to-maplong-string-using-guava) and [Why Guava does not provide a way to transform map keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991710/why-guava-do-not-provide-a-way-to-transform-map-keys) for details as to why.

In short, it's not possible to efficiently provide key transformations in the general case.  Rather than creating the complex and possibly inconsistent data structure you're envisioning, the best thing to do is likely to just [create a new dict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) applying your key transformation, e.g.:

```
{ f(k): v for k, v in d.iteritems() }
```

Comment: Any feedback, downvoter?  I'm citing an example of a (well respected) library in another language, and suggesting doing the same thing here.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if PEP 274 (Dict Comprehensions) is relevant here, because you don't know in advance what queries will be made and you can't create a new `dict` object that will satisfy all future queries.

Comment: @musiphil The PEP 274 link was just to suggest a concise way to construct your new dict, you don't have to use dict comprehensions if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the idiomatic way to do it is probably using dimo414's answer. For the case where the transform is not pure (do not always evaluates the same result value given the same argument):

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self, transform, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        assert isfunction(transform), u'Transform argument must be a function.'
        self._transform = transform
    def get(self, k, d=None):
        return super(Foo, self).get(self._transform(k), d)
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return super(Foo, self).__getitem__(self._transform(item))
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return super(Foo, self).__contains__(self._transform(item))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Foo instance {}>'.format(id(self))
```

Testing:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> # {0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2' ... 99: '99'}
>>> x = Foo(lambda x: (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds, ((i, str(i)) for i in range(10)))
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> x.get(t)
'5'
>>> x[t]
'12'
```

Not that tedious but I don't like how it smells (in terms of design).

Comment: I'm not sure if inheriting from `dict` is a good idea: the new class' initialization method does not have the same signature, so it cannot be substituted for a `dict`.

Comment: @EOL so a children class must have the same signature as its parent  ... is it really true for Python? Honest question - if you have pointers for a discussion about it I would love to read the material.

Comment: Good question. :) The last time I checked, I did not see strong arguments against using a different signature. However, it is usual to be able to substitute subclasses for the parent class (see for instance the documentation for `collections.OrderedDict`, which mentions that it can be used "anywhere" its parent class, `dict`, is used). In any case, having the same constructor signature is arguably more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to maintain the exact same signature as `dict()`, I
propose creating a factory function to wrap a `TransformDict` to provide
the same signature.

```
def transform_dict(transform_key):
    def _transform_dict(*args, **kwargs):
        return TransformDict(transform_key, *args, **kwargs)
    return _transform_dict
```

Which can be used as:

```
>>> LowerDict = transform_dict(lambda k: k.lower())
>>> lower_dict = LowerDict({'FOO': 1}, BaR=2)
TransformDict(<function <lambda> at 0x12345678>, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
```

The `TransformDict` should implement the [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) abstract
base class so that any potentially missed `dict` method will not pass
silently. All methods dealing with transforming the key can be
implemented in terms of [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__),
[`__setitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__), and [`__delitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__).

```
import collections
import sys

class TransformDict(collections.MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, __transform_key, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        self.transform_key = __transform_key

    # Key methods.

    def __contains__(self, key):
        key = self.transform_key(key)
        return key in self.data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = self.transform_key(key)
        return self.data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = self.transform_key(key)
        self.data[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        key = self.transform_key(key)
        del self.data[key]

    # Operator methods.

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, TransformDict):
          other = other.data
        return self.data == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({!r}, {!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.transform_key, self.data)

    # Accessor methods.

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        return default

    def keys(self):
        return self.data.keys()

    def items(self):
        return self.data.items()

    def values(self):
        return self.data.values()

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:

      def iterkeys(self):
          return self.data.iterkeys()

      def itervalues(self):
          return self.data.itervalues()

      def iteritems(self):
          return self.data.iteritems()

      def viewkeys(self):
          return self.data.viewkeys()

      def viewvalues(self):
          return self.data.viewvalues()

      def viewitems(self):
          return self.data.viewitems()

    # Mutable methods.

    def clear(self):
        self.data.clear()

    def pop(self, key, default=KeyError):
        if key in self or default is KeyError:
            value = self[key]
            del self[key]
            return value
        return default

    def popitem(self):
        return self.data.popitem()

    def setdefault(self, key, default=None):
      if key not in self:
        self[key] = default
        return default
      return self[key]

    def update(self, other):
        for key for other:
            self[key] = other[key]

    # Miscellaneous methods.

    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self.transform_key, self.data)
```